# Best Way to manage Sessions in Flex SpringBlazeDS project

Tags: spring, blazeds

Am new to Spring framework, Have manage to integrate Flex SpringBlazeDS by following some samples on the net.

What am trying to see is the best approach to go ahead with managing sessions at backend.

Any Ideas or links for sample implementations will help me alot.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the sessions? -- That is important for "best" something.

Comment: Hi Ralph, to maintain a simple User Object. Like User preferences.

Comment: I load UserPreferences through RemoteCall right after Login. This is a very trivial case. Nevertheless Session handling in Flex has some pitfalls. You need to decide if ie. every browser window should have it's own Flex Session with one shared server session or if the server session should be the same like the flex session. I always add some remote methods that I call right after login and before I logout. You can also handle this through some listeners but I didn't tried them yet.

Answer (score 0):

When I remember right, the normal Session Handling can be used (like a normal HTML Web App). BlazeDS Flex uses the normal network stack.